# How to map three elements of different types in Spark Shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

After creating a RDD from a textfile, I need to use .map to create a new RDD of type [Int,String,String]...each element split by a comma delim. I don’t understand how to define a RDD with three different data types per record....

So far I have:

```scala
val abc1 = sc.textFile("hi.txt")
val abc2 = abc1.map(i => i.split(,))
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are reading a text file to create an `RDD[String]`, where each string is a record (line) in the file. However, these records contain an integer value, followed by two string values, with a comma delimiter. (For example, a record might be something like "5,string1,string2".)

An `RDD` can indeed only have a single type of record. It seems that you want to obtain a type that is a `RDD[(Int, String, String)]`—where the type of the `RDD` is a *tuple* of an `Int`, a `String`, and a `String`. (This is a shorthand for `RDD[Tuple3[Int, String, String]]`, incidentally. If you're unfamiliar with *Scala* tuples, [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_tuples.htm) might help.)

Is that correct?

If so, `map` is an appropriate operation. However, the `.split` operation will return an `Array[String]`, so the following will result in an `RDD[Array[String]]` as the type of `abc2`.

```scala
val abc1 = sc.textFile("hi.txt")
val abc2 = abc1.map(_.split(","))
```

BTW, the use of the underscore, `_`, is a shorthand for the following:

```scala
val abc1 = sc.textFile("hi.txt")
val abc2 = abc1.map(s => s.split(","))
```

In order to get the type you require, you should use an expression something like the following:

```scala
val abc1 = sc.textFile("hi.txt")
val abc2 = abc1.map {s =>

  // Split the string into tokens, delimited by a comma, put result in an array.
  val a = s.split(",")

  // Create a tuple of the expected values, converting the first value to an integer.
  (a(0).toInt, a(1), a(2))
}
```

Note that this assumes you always have three elements, and that the first is an integer. You will get errors if this is not the case (and you may want to add more error handling).